# Conversion 12-hour to 24-hour format with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple clock with javascript in 24-hour format. As far as i've come i only managed to get a 12-hour format. The script is really simple actually, here what i've got:

```
<div id="updatetime"></div>
<script>
        setInterval(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_hour = d.getHours();
        var curr_minute = d.getMinutes() + 1;
        document.getElementById("updatetime").innerHTML = curr_hour + ":" + curr_minute;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

as for my question: How do i convert the 12-hour output to a 24-hour output while still keeping it simple. Only the hours and minutes are needed.

Comment: [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) already returns the hours in 24-hour format

Comment: What are expected results? Question doesn't make sense based on code shown since as already pointed out hours are in 24 hour format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date().getHours()` *does* return the time in 24-hour format. To get 12-hour time from it, one simply uses the modulus operator (`Date().getHours() % 12`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

You should check that your clock is properly set and that it is past noon in your time zone.