# How to display the 12-hour format

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and need a little help. I found a clock javascript and I am trying to change the time format to the 12-hour format. How can I modify the code below to run on the 12-hour format?

```
function updateTime(){
        var currentTime = new Date()
        var hour = pad( currentTime.getHours(), 2);
        var minutes = pad( currentTime.getMinutes(), 2);
        var hour_1 = hour.substr(0,1);
        var hour_2 = hour.substr(1,2);
        var minute_1 = minutes.substr(0,1);
        var minute_2 = minutes.substr(1,2);
```

Thanks in advance for any help/comments.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion 12-hour to 24-hour format with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338194/conversion-12-hour-to-24-hour-format-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format)

Comment: I looked at these links prior to posting. I tried what was suggested in each one, and none of the worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment js for any date operations.

```js
console.log(moment().format('hh:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend a good date formatting library. However, if you are new to programming and want to learn how to do it yourself you could also use a modulo operator.

```
currentTime.getHours() % 12
```

The modulo operator (%) gives the remainder of a integer division.